# Cron Job run PHP with _Get params from database

Tags: php, cron

I'm running a cron job that runs another php script based on database values.

I need to pass in some paramaters from the database. I was originally trying with the following.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $url = "test.php?msg=".$row['message']."&phone=".$row['phone'];
 exec($url);
}
```

It fails to run. What's the best way to pass the information into test.php ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your exec() command is not complete, you need to do something like

```
exec('wget http://www.mywebsite.com/' . $url);
```

also try dumping the return

```
exec($url,$output,$retval);
var_dump($output,$retval);
```

Comment: maybe his php script is local and executable from command line, and not hosted somewhere.. btw is missing the full path

Comment: true ... @PhilipK ... can you post the error you are receiving?

Comment: @PhilipK try dumping the return and ouput, I added some code above

Comment: returns: *array(0) { } int(0)*

Comment: try adding . " 2>&1" to $url and see if you get anything, make sure you are reporting all errors, check to see if there is an error log in your directory that may contain errors. can you run test outside of the CRON job ?

Comment: Realized a huge downside to this. If you are executing a url with get parameter this actually saves a file for every url query. e.g. url.com?q=1, url.com?q=2, url.com?q=3, ect., ect. Is there an alternative to wget?